# Firebase: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInWithEmailAndPassword'

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm doing simple signup by following YT tuts, link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU)
There i have this script in `app.js`
 and i'm getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInWithEmailAndPassword'
>   of undefined
>       at HTMLInputElement.btnLogin.addEventListener.e (app.js:26)

```
// GET Users info
const txtEmail    = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
const btnLogin    = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
const btnSignUp   = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
const btnLogout   = document.getElementById('btnLogout');

//Add login event
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  "use strict";
  const email = txtEmail.value;
  const pass  = txtPassword.value;
  const auth  = firebase.value;

  // Sign in
  const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass);
  promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

});
```

and on line 26 i have `const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass);` seems like i miss including any `auth` library but i have included scripts in `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Smart Media Compaing</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/1.0.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/1.0.0/firebaseui.css" />

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.6/firebase.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message">
      <input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="user_email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" name="user_password" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-action" value="Login" name="submit">
      <button id="btnSignup" class="btn btn-secondary">
        Sign Up
      </button>
      <button id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-action hide">
        Log Out
      </button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword

Check the documentation here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

**UPDATE**

As per the video you have mentioned , this is wrongly set in your example

```
const auth  = firebase.value;
```

it should be

```
const auth  = firebase.auth();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your app then call `auth()` correctly.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Then call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: obviously i'm doing this other wise it wouldn't even run ?
And i get this error when i submit the form (means on button click)

Comment: it's not "obvious" because 1) you didn't post the initialization code and 2) it isn't running. you're trying to copy+paste code from a youtube video and you did it incorrectly. http://imgur.com/a/ls4DF

Comment: yes you are right, just corrected this mistake now its working :(