# How to deploy Angular+Firebase app locally on Ubuntu

Tags: angular, firebase, ubuntu, localhost

I am using the firebase database to create a simple Angular application to add items and list them, everything works great with **ng serve**. But when I deploy it following the right tutorial steps of angular firebase app https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/deploying-an-angular-app-to-firebase/

1. `firebase init (with database)`
2. `ng build --prod`
3. `firebase deploy`

After it's done a new folder is created called **dist** that contains the deployed application, so in order to run this folder on my localhost, I use the **http-server** command.

```
http-server dist
```

It runs on localhost:8080 but the page that lists the firebase items doesn't show anything and the error I have found on google chrome console was:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseURL' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'databaseURL' of undefined
    at t.databaseFromApp (main.aa361c76a38235bc8275.js:1)
    at Object.e.INTERNAL.registerService.Reference [as database]
```

I can't find anyone with this similar problem if someone could know the problem would mean a lot, it looks like if no firebase is deployed...

There is this guy on stackoverflow who had same error [Firebase: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signInWithEmailAndPassword'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200009/firebase-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-signinwithemailandpassword)

But he has forgotten to add properly the firebase settings in my case I repeat with **ng serve** everything works great and firebase settings are connected!.